# Inference for the Zeta distribution

Tags: distributions, estimation, inference, descriptive-statistics, sufficient-statistics

I have a problem where I am aware that data is well-modeled by a [Zeta distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zeta_distribution) such as $P(X=x) = x^{-a}/\zeta(a)$, and would like to learn the Zeta distribution parameter $a$ from the data. More explicitely, I would like to turn the knowledge of the mean $\mu$ of the distribution that I obtained from data, to the knowledge of the parameter $a$ in the underlying Zeta distribution. Is there a simple analytical relationship between $a$ and $\mu$?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since one knows the distribution of the data, the likelihood is available as
$$L(a|x_1,\ldots,x_n) = \zeta(a)^{-n} \prod_{i=1}^n x_i^{-a} = \zeta(a)^{-n} \left\{\prod_{i=1}^n x_i\right\}^{-a}$$
which shows that the geometric mean $$\exp\left\{\sum_{i=1}^n\log(x_i)/n\right\}$$ [rather than the sample average] is a sufficient statistic for this problem.

And the [mean of the Zeta distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zeta_distribution) is given by $\mu=\zeta(a-1)/\zeta(a)$, which means that a first moment equation can be solved numerically if not analytically.

Comment: Ok thanks - so there is no analytical solution at hand.

Comment: In the first equation, shouldn't zeta be raised to the power of $-n$ (not $-1$) and each $x_i$ to the power of $-a$ (not $a$)?

Comment: No problem. However, I don't really understand what follows from this likelihood. The question is how to fit $a$ to the sample, so we are looking for maximum likelihood. What $a$ will maximize this likelihood? I don't see it, and I don't understand how you get to the geometric mean... Could you elaborate?

Comment: By the way, regarding the last paragraph: the mean is only finite for $a>2$ so I guess if true $a$ is less than 2, then method of moments is invalid?..